How to use New York Extra Large in SwiftUI as a System Font?
I want to use the New York Extra Large, New York Small etc fonts in SwiftUI, as they have a specific optical size.
I know I can use New York as a system font via .serif, so how can I access Extra Large etc as a system font?
RN I'm using
Text("Text")
                .font(.system(size: 64, weight: .bold, design: .serif))

But I can't set optical size here/use ExtraLarge presets

iOS should determine which size to use automatically based on font size. In your current approach, how do you know it is not using Extra Large already?

I have reference images

I'm not sure how you would figure that out using reference images... In any case, it is totally possible that 64pt is not large enough for the system to decide that Extra Large is appropriate. How about using a larger font size?

These are the default fonts provided: http://iosfonts.com
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Text")
            .font(Font.custom("Academy Engraved LET", size: 64))
    }
}

Custom fonts need to be added separately in Xcode.

If you wish to use a predefined size, use Font's system(_:design:weight:) initializer:
Text("Hello")
    .font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .serif, weight: .bold))

This will draw the text in New York font with a "large title" size and bold weight. The first parameter is the font size, the next is the design, and the third is the weight.
If you wish to use a custom size, use the system(size:weight:design:) initializer:
Text("Hello")
    .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .bold, design: .serif))

This will draw in New York font with size 17.

but this won't let me set the size, Ill have to use a predefined one

@MoPaMo, See updated answer; use the system(size:weight:design:) initializer.

I'm not sure if you can access the New York font directly: maybe try .font(.custom("New York Extra Large", size: 16))?
